# Webtoon where a swordsman is killed and travels back in time. Becomes a mage and learns his father had him murdered

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

I'm looking for a Webtoon.

- The main character was killed by his friend.
- I think he was a swordsman before he went back into time and changed to be a mage.
- He copied power from a girl.
- He found out his dad sent his friend to kill him.

<sub><sup>It's not Revenge of the Iron-Blooded Sword Hound</sup></sub>

Comment: This question is very terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: In particular, what was the main character's name? Where did he live? What was the setting (e.g. medieval, fantasy, etc)? What was the target audience (e.g. was there any sex or gore)? What was his friend's name? How did his friend kill him? Why did his father want to kill him? As a mage, what powers did he possess?

Comment: its not revenge of the iron blooded sword hound

Comment: Any answers to the question above and in the checklist?

Comment: To clarify your use of Webtoon, you're referring to a (likely) Chinese or Korean long-strip manga, correct?

Comment: yes its a  korean webtoon

Comment: Can you clarify when the bullet points occur in the story? "The Swordmaster's Son" has the MC betrayed and goes back in time, but no mention of a friend, at least in the first chapter. Is the friend being behind it known right away? What about the girl he copies power from, or discovering his dad was the real culprit?

Comment: i have bad memory but thats all i know and i read the swordmaster son and its not it. i remeber the girl he copyed from is triang him and he was in a cupe he had to get out from if that make since

Comment: But you have no idea when that happens? Chapter 1? 10? 80?

Comment: no ugh im sorry

Comment: "9th Class Sword Master"? Betrayed by friend, reincarnates, immediately wants to learn magic. I haven't seen a single girl at all, let alone one he "copies" from. "Return of the Legendary Spear Knight"? Betrayed by friend and emperor; reincarnates. Not a sword user. He learns some mana tricks but I don't see it called magic. I didn't see any "copying" in the few chapters I skimmed, but there are at least some women in this story. I'm not seeing any other potential matches.

Comment: thank u again but its not it awww ugh ooh will mayby thie 2 seprete webtoons

Answer (score 2):

***[Mythic Item Obtained](https://www.kenmei.co/series/i-obtained-a-mythic-item)* (AKA *I Obtained a Mythic Item*)**

> *In a world where technology and magic are almost indistinguishable from one another, monsters and creatures of myth and legend reign terror upon mankind. In humanity’s darkest moment, individuals with special god-like powers emerge to save the day. They are — the Awakened. Meet Jaehyeon, a feeble Awakened human Raider, who struggles to make ends meet until one day a series of confounding events allow him to claim a powerful item that will change the course of history forever…*
>
> [image]

Most of the bullet points can be confirmed by reading the first 4 chapters: him choosing to become a swordsman and not a mage, his father hiring assassins to kill him off and one of them being his acquaintance; him going back in time after that, etc.

Comment: I haven't read it too far in, but most of the bullet points can be confirmed by reading the first 4 chapters: him choosing to become a swordsman and not a mage, his father hiring assassins to kill him off and one of them being his acquaintance; him going back in time after that

Comment: Great. I've [edited](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/279580/edit) that into the answer :-)